# Declare multiple variables in an Oracle SQL function

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to use multiple local variables in my SQL block but I always get some errors. I only have to `return` the `sum of salary`. Any ideas?

```
function Foo(projekt varchar2)
return number
  is sumSalary number;
  cursor kurzor is (
     select * 
       from (hr.employees inner join hr.workon using (employee_id))
            inner join hr.proj using (projno));
  oneLine kurzor%ROWTYPE;
begin
  sumSalary := 0;
  for oneLine in kurzor
  loop
    if oneLine.pname = projekt then
      dbms_output.put_line(concat(concat(oneLine.first_name,' '),oneLine.last_name));
      sumSalary := sumSalary+ oneLine.salary;
    end if;
    if oneLine.salary > 7500 then
      insert into HighSalary values(oneLine.first_name,oneLine.salary);
    end if;
  end loop;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('asd');
end;
```

My error:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PLS-00201: identifier
>   'SUMSALARY' must be declared ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 3, column 15: PLS-00201: identifier
>   'KURZOR' must be declared ORA-06550: line 3, column 1: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: First of all. You specify a name of a formal parameter first then its type not vise versa. Second. Do not specify size of a formal `varchar2` parameter of a function or a procedure. Third. Do not declare a cursor loop variable explicitly, it'll be declare implicitly by the cursor `for` loop. Fourth. `sumfizu` isn't declared... well, rewrite your procedure completely. I's completely, semantically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How to format error like that?
I change my code the way you said, though as far as I reckon one can use explicite cursors, it shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: I wasn't talking about explicit cursors, I was talking about explicitly declared cursor `for` loop variables.

Comment: I edit that sumfizu out, the code is transleted, though I missed a variable translation.

Comment: Now for those `cursor` changes. How to do those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Foo(projekt varchar2)
return number
is sumSalary number; // remove this semicolon
cursor kurzor is (
```